# How to extend qweb templates in Odoo14?

Tags: javascript, qweb, odoo-14

I'm trying to add custom menu item in filter's dropdown list

in Odoo14 and owl framework some menu items exists in the base module inside the following snippet

```xml
<t t-name="web.CustomFilterItem" owl="1">
    <div class="o_generator_menu">
        <button type="button"
            class="o_add_custom_filter dropdown-item"
            aria-expanded="false"
            t-ref="fallback-focus"
            t-on-click="state.open = !state.open"
            t-on-keydown="_onKeydown"
            >
            <t>Add Custom Filter</t>
        </button>
    </div>
</t>
```

So in my custom module am doing the following to add custom item

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<templates>
    <t t-extend="web.CustomFilterItem">
        <t t-jquery=".o_add_custom_filter" t-operation="after">
            <div
                role="separator"
                class="dropdown-divider o_generator_menu"
            />
            <button
                type="button"
                class="dropdown-item o_generator_menu o_add_advanced_search"
                aria-expanded="false"
            >Custom Item</button>
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

But it doesn't appear. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Odoo14 owl framework you can extend template using xpath.

you can use like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
<t t-name="CustomFilterItem" t-inherit="web.CustomFilterItem" t-inherit-mode="extension" owl="1">
<xpath expr="//button[hasclass('o_add_custom_filter dropdown-item')]" position="before">
//your code
</xpath>
</templates>
```